# trying 2 requests in order(frontend, javascript, promise)

Tags: javascript, promise, frontend, aurelia

I'm trying to make http requests one to upload file func"uploadFile(file)" and the other is to link my upload id to my user using this func "linkAvatar(id)" the problem is i need the uploadFile(file) finished first because that func gives me the id so i can use the linkAvatar(id) func.

My http-service:

```
import {CustomHttpClient} from '../../../customHttpClient';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(CustomHttpClient)
export class FilesHttpService {

  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  //upload file request
  uploadFile(file) {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('filename', file.name);

    return this.http.post('v1/files', data);
  }

  // linkAvatar request
  linkAvatar(id) {
    return this.http.patch('v1/users/me/video/'+id);
  }
}
```

My component:

```
import {bindable, customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {AuthService} from 'wanderlima/aurelia-auth';
import {CustomHttpClient} from '../../../../customHttpClient';
import {FilesHttpService} from '../../services/files-http-service';
import {UserHttpService} from '../../services/user-http-service';

@inject(AuthService, CustomHttpClient, FilesHttpService, UserHttpService)

@customElement('zm-zoome-yourself')
export class ZmZoomeYourself {

  constructor(auth, http, fileUpload) {
    this.auth = auth.auth.getToken();
    this.http = http;
    this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
    //this.avatarUpload = userfile;
  }

  endRecord(file) {
    let msg = '';
    this.zoomeYourself = file;
    this.stopCount();
    //Is making this request but is not handling the response with .then() it goes to the other func linkAvatar(id) without entering .then
    this.fileUpload.uploadFile(file).then(function(res) {
      //Is entering this block of code only after linkAvatar(id)
      if (res.statusCode === 201) {
        var id = res.content.id;
        msg = 'upload realizado com sucesso!';
      } else {
        msg = 'ocorreu um erro ao enviar o arquivo';
      }
    });
    return this.fileUpload.linkAvatar(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Some indentation would help to make this answerable.

Comment: Can you move `this.fileUpload.linkAvatar(id)` inside then `this.fileUpload.uploadFile(file).then(...)` callback?

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.fileUpload.uploadFile(file).then(function(res) {
      //Is entering this block of code only after linkAvatar(id)
      if (res.statusCode === 201) {
        var id = res.content.id;
        msg = 'upload realizado com sucesso!';
         return id;//we will return id
      } else {
        msg = 'ocorreu um erro ao enviar o arquivo';
throw msg;// we will throw exception
      }
    })
.then(fileUpload.linkAvatar) // if upload is ok, we will pass id to linkAvatar and execute;
.catch(function(error)){
console.log(error);
alert('Unexpected error');
}
```

try rewrite like this
after upload is finishid - return id to next promise
next promise, linkAvatar, will receive this id and will execute your second request

Comment: In genereal, what if after your upload, client will loose connection to internet. File will be stored, but not linked? And if user will reupload file, it will be duplicated? Also, links with API version, v1. You can add API version with request interceptor.